# Output isn't true

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int inches = 0; 
    int yards = 0;
    int feet = 0;
    const int inches per foot = 12;
    const int feet_per yard = 3;
    printf("Enter a distance in inches: ");
    scanf ("%d", &inches);
    feet = inches/inches_per_foot;
    yards = feet/feet_per_yard; feet %= feet_per_yard;
    inches %= inches_per_foot;
    printf("That is equivalent to %d yards %d feet and %d inches.\n",      
    printf("or %d centimeters\n", inches*2.54);
}
```

Input:
Enter a distance in inches: 10

Output:
That is equivalent to 0 yards 0 feet and 10 inches.
or 1717986918 centimeters.

So, what is 1717986918?

Comment: Try `printf("%.6f", inches*2.54);`

Comment: If you do not make an effort when posting the question, no one would make an effort to answer.

Comment: "So, what is 1717986918?" This is result of cheating on your compiler or the `printf` function. With `%d` you promised you would provide a corresponding `int` value but instead you throw a `double` value at it. Your compiler might even have mentioned a type mismatch in that function call.

Comment: There is no reason to reopen this since it is just another boring "wrong format specificer" question, for which there exists numerous duplicates. It will just get closed again.

Answer (score 3):

> So, what is 1717986918?

It's what happens when you try to print a `double` as if it were an `int`.

```
printf("or %d centimeters. \n", inches *2.54);
```

Because `inches *2.54` involves a multiplication by a floating point number, `inches` is implicitly cast to `double` and the result is a `double`. Use `%f` to print a `double`

```
printf("or %f centimeters. \n", inches *2.54);
```